# How can I switch a bitlocked drive from password protected to TPM-only?

Tags: windows-11, bitlocker

My OS drive (Windows 11, drive C:) is currently password protected.  I want to Remote Desktop into it, so I want to remove the password protection and let TPM handle it.

The Control Panel Bitlocker page doesn't have "Change how drive is unlocked at startup" as an option.  And when I type `manage-bde -protectors -add C: -tpm`
I get this error:

> A TPM key protector cannot be added because a password protector
> exists on the drive.

I have the Bitlocker Operating System Drives group policy set as follows:

- Require Additional authentication at startup: Enabled.
- Allow BitLocker without compatible TPM: unchecked
- Configure TPM startup: Allow (I also tried "require")
- Configure TPM startup PIN: Allow
- the rest of the options: Do not allow

The results of `manage-bde -status C:`

> ```
> BitLocker Version:    2.0
> Conversion Status:    Fully Encrypted
> Percentage Encrypted: 100.0%
> Encryption Method:    XTS-AES 128
> Protection Status:    Protection On
> Lock Status:          Unlocked
> Identification Field: Unknown
> Key Protectors:
>     Password
>     Numerical Password
> ```

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: The only way I figured out how to do it was to unencrypt the drive and start the encryption process over.

Answer (score 3):

First get the status of your hard drive:
'Manage-bde -status c:'

Next, then delete the password related information:
'Manage-bde – protectors -delete c: -type password'

Next, Add TPM to the list:
'Manage-bde -protectors -add c: -tpm'